# Can I collect all Js file names into a variable as a list from specific html page with out loading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

For example we have a html file `index.html`. Which includes lot of script, tags and links to include js and css files respectively. Now I need to collect all the filenames from `index.html` without loading the page. If I load it we can get it by document. But without loading the page how can I get all the JavaScript and css file names ?

Comment: Go through it by hand and copy the filenames down? Sounds like you're looking for a programmatic solution when you don't need one.

Comment: @K correct asking for parsing html file

Comment: @Andy: for the first time it could be done, but adding more of js files to the index.html, every time it will be manual and hectic